# Prove (f(z*))* is regular on D*= {z | z* in D} if f(z) is regular on D

Tags: complex-analysis

I think the following question

Prove 
$(f(z^\times))^\times$ is regular on $D^\times= \{z | z^\times \in D\}$ if $f(z)$ is regular on $D$

is not correct as a question.

It is because $f(z^\times)$ is regular on $D^\times$, so $(f(z^\times))^\times$ can not be regular (except that $f(z)$ is a constant function.)

Is it right?

Also it requires to prove that
 derivative of $(f(z^\times))^\times$ is $(f’(z^\times))^\times$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use power series expansion. This becomes obvious if you notice that if the conjugat eof $\sum a_n \overset {-} z^{n} $ is  $\sum  \overset {-} {a_n}  z^{n}$

Comment: Oh I see. My thanks to you.